# EF6 seeding via initializer and one-to-many ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, initializer, icollection

I am following the EF6 code first walk-through, and have tried to adapt it slightly to suit my own project, but I have run into a problem when seeding the database with the initializer.

I have created 2 classes:

A property mode:

```
namespace MyApp.Models

{
    public class Property
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public virtual PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a property type mode:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class PropertyType
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that there is a one-to-many relationship between these 2. A property can only be 1 property type, but many properties can have the same property types?

However, when I try to initialize the context and seed the database (using the code below), I get an error:

```
    public class MyAppInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyAppContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyAppContext context)
    {
        var propertytypedata = new List<PropertyType>
        {
            new PropertyType {ID = 1, Type="Villa" },
            new PropertyType {ID = 2, Type="Apartment" }
        };

        propertytypedata.ForEach(p => context.PropertyType.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var propertydata = new List<Property>
        {
            new Property {PropertyName="Property 1", PropertyType=1, }
        };

        propertydata.ForEach(p => context.Property.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The issue is, that when I try to set the property type on the property I am seeding, it says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'MyApp.Models.PropertyType'

Comment: `PropertyType=1,`. PropertyType is a complex object, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
protected override void Seed(MyAppContext context)
    {
        var propertytypedata = new List<PropertyType>
        {
            new PropertyType {ID = 1, Type="Villa" },
            new PropertyType {ID = 2, Type="Apartment" }
        };

        foreach(var propertyType in propertytypedata){                 
             propertyType.Properties = new List<Property>
             {
                 new Property {PropertyName="Property 1", PropertyType = propertyType, }
             };
             context.PropertyType.Add(propertyType)
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

You don't need two separate adds. Entity Framework will add the sub collection to the database. Whenever you access that propertyType now it will have the properties as a sub collection already loaded if you mark `ICollection<Property> Properties` as `virtual`, otherwise you'll need to `include()` it when you load.